# Problem of Function of one variable

Tags: functions, derivatives

Q) Let $ f:\Bbb R\rightarrow \ \Bbb R$  be a differentiable function such that $f(2)=2$ and $$ |f(x)-f(y)|\le 5(|x-y|)^{3/2} $$ for all  $ x,y  \in \Bbb R.$ Let $ g(x)=x^3f(x)$. Then find $g'(2)$ (derivative of $g$ at $2$).

A) By product rule I know that $ g'(2)=3*2^2f(2)+2^3f'(2) $. How do I find $f'(2)$ ?

Comment: Just a tip for writing in mathjax, you can use `\in` to give the $\in$ symbol

Comment: $g'(x)=x^3 f'(x)+f(x) 3x^2$. Now given inequality tells what $f'$ is!

Comment: You have been on this site long enough to know that the way to get help is to show your work so far and where you are stuck. Otherwise you get only votes to close.

Answer (score 1):

A) $$ |f(x)-f(y)| \leq 5(|x-y|)^{3/2}$$

$$ \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \leq5(|x-y|)^{1/2} $$

$$ \lim_{x\to y} |\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}| \leq \lim_{x\to y} 5(|x-y|)^{1/2}$$

We know that 
 $$lim_{x\to y}|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|=|f'(x)|$$ and $$\lim_{x\to y}5(|x-y|)^{1/2}=0$$
so $$ |f'(x)|\leq0 $$ but since $|f'(x)|$ cannot be less than zero so $$ |f'(x)|=0 \ or \ f'(x)=0$$ so since $$ g'(2)=3*2^2f(2)+2^3f'(2)$$ $$ g'(2)=12*2+0=24$$